# C/C++ omp: locking features

Tags: c++, c, locks, openmp

I'm trying to move from pthreads to openmp, I have a application that I tinker with... I'm trying to find out what kind of locking features that's available. I have to lock parts of a global array where the locked part is significantly smaller than the global array. Example in pseudo:

```
array={0,1,2... ...n};
...
lock (4,654,1777)
//do something thread safe
unlock (4,654,1777)
...
```

Is this locking set up possible in openmp?